# Replacing every member of a structure in upper case

Tags: c++, boost

I've a c++ struct, with 100 string members in it. I need to do search and replace in each member of it.

One way, is to do it for every member. Is there a better way?

```
typedef struct
{
   std::string m;
   std::string x;
} datamembers;

void replace( datamembers& src)
{
   std::transform(src.m.begin() , src.m.end(), src.m.begin(), ::toupper);
   std::transform(src.x.begin() , src.x.end(), src.x.begin(), ::toupper);
}
```

Comment: What are these strings being used for?

Comment: Unless they're in an array, there's no simple way to do it (since you can't depend on the struct layout).

Comment: Sure there's a better way, put all the members into a std::vector<std::string>, then iterate over that vector in your replace code

Comment: I don't own the original code and thus, I cannot replace the structure. However, I need to parse the members of the structure before using it.

Comment: if the `struct` consisted of char arrays it could be done, but in the case of a `struct` with `string`s, the `struct` acts more like a container with strings all over the place in memory. i think you are stuck with your method `replace()`

Comment: Yes Claptrap. The struct is a contains std::string and not char*.

Comment: If you can't change the struct, you can at least think about writing a wrapper for it.  A vector is a good start, but also think about using a map, where the key is the variable name and the value is the value in the struct.

Comment: Are there other operations you want to do on all the strings, or is it only one operation: upper-casing all the strings?

Comment: I actually want to replace certain characters like ' with " etc.,

Answer (score 2):

I would use pointer to members?

For example:

```
typedef struct {
  std::string m;
  std::string x;
} datamembers;

std::vector<std::string datamembers::*> memptrs;
void init_members() {
  memptrs.push_back(&datamembers::m);
  memptrs.push_back(&datamembers::x);
}

void replace( datamembers& src)
{
  for (auto m = memptrs.begin(); m!=memptrs.end(); m++) {
   std::transform((src.*(*m)).begin() , (src.*(*m)).end(), (src.*(*m)).begin(), ::toupper);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 100 string members, I think the best would be to refactor this class to have a vector of strings instead of those members. In this case any operation on all fields will be trivial - just iterate through container.

I can hardly imagine how can you manage 100 members in the class.

Comment: I don't own the original code and thus, I cannot replace the structure. However, I need to parse the members of the structure before using it.

Comment: @user373215 Ok, I see. Unfortunately you can't iterate through different members without resorting to hacks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not claim that what follows is a good idea, portable, reliable, or in any way recommended. However, if what you are doing is a one-off thing and you just need to Get Your Job Done, you can try the following.

You can use `offsetof` to get the offset of the second member, and then use that as a step with some pointer manipulation. E.g.:

```
#include <stddef.h> /*<- offsetof from here */

typedef struct 
{
   std::string a;
   std::string b;
   ...
} datamembers;

void replace( datamembers& src)
{
    size_t step = offsetof(datamembers, b); //<- get second member
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(src); i += step) {
        std::string *p = (std::string *)((char*)(&src) + i);
        std::transform(p->begin() , p->end(), p->begin(), ::toupper);
    }
}
```

Note that this is such a bad idea that GCC even warns you about using `offsetof` this way. You can suppress that if you want using `-Wno-invalid-offsetof` (if you're using GCC).

Like I said, I'm pretty sure this is not *guaranteed* to work for all compilers on all structs, at all times of the day, however it might work for you in your particular case, and if it does, maybe it's good enough and allows you to get on with your day.

However, if you're making an auto-pilot for a commercial jet-liner or something, please do not do this.